# update some part of the webpage?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4

[image]

for quick reference I have attached the image of what I want.
I would like to update (change the content) without updating the whole page (without refreshing the page). Clicking on the links or buttons on the whitebox should fetch the data from the database and that is to be displayed in the redbox. Of course first thing you would write as an answer will be "Ajax!!!", but as I'm new to `laravel framework`, I want to know what is the best way to achieve this, should I write the `javascript` directly in the view or in the controller, and how to do it through controller? If you need any more info please let me know.

**Revised question, is there any other better way other then the ones answered**

Comment: You can use PrimeFaces Ajax POLL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need to set up some routes. You can also do this with controllers.

```
Route::get('home', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});

Route::get('someRoute', function()
{
    return View::make('someView');
});
```

For the home view, I'd add a scripts section:

```
//home.php

<html>
<head>
    <script>
    $('a.ajax').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var pageURL = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#ajaxContent').load(pageURL);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="{{URL::to('someRoute')}}" class="ajax">Click Here</a>
        <div id="ajaxContent"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In case you're using blade templating, here's an implementation

```
//main.blade.php

<html>
<head>
    @yield('styles')
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
    @section('scripts')
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @show
</body>
</html>

//home.blade.php
@extends('main')

@section('content')
    <a href="<?=URL::to('someRoute')?>" class="ajax">Click Here</a>
        <div id="ajaxContent"></div>
@stop

@section('scripts')
    @parent
    $('a.ajax').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageURL = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#ajaxContent').load(pageURL);
    });
@stop
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I know this, I wanted to know is there any other better way to do it.

Comment: I think this depends on use. If your templates are modules, meaning you'll include snippets of multiple views then you'll want to override sections or even create a view that holds all your javascript and include it. If you're not concerned about modularity then the first option may be better. Either way, your javascript should be in the views, not the controllers. The other alternative is to use iframes but I don't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

it would be better for you if you use `jQuery` to do this update using ajax functionality.
and a simple code can be like this

```
$('a.ajax').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var pageURL = $(this).attr('href');
     $('#divID-to-be-updated').load(pageURL);
});
```

more about ajax functionality inside jQuery can be read from http://jqapi.com/#p=load